# Creating a difference object of two POJOs

Tags: java

(This is just a question out of convenience. Right now I'm doing it manually, but ideally, there should be a library that already takes care of this, but I just couldn't find any.)

Basically, I'd like to take two objects A and B of the same class (same one, no inheritance) and create a new one with just the differences that were introduced in B for every field, keeping the remaining fields set to null. Of course I could just manually call every single getter and do an equals, then set the field, but that would be a lot of boilerplate.

So far I was only able to find solutions for *comparing* two objects, as in, all that would be returned is a boolean. But that wouldn't take away the problem of still having to manually check every single field. I had something like this in mind:

```
class MyPojo {
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
   private String field3;
  
   // ... getters and setters here ...
}

MyPojo oldObj = new MyPojo("a", "b", "c");
MyPojo newObj = new MyPojo("a", "b", "x");

MyPojo diff = createDifferenceObject(oldObj, newObj);
assert(diff.getField1() == null);
assert(diff.getField2() == null);
assert(diff.getField3() == "x");

public MyPojo createDifferenceObject(MyPojo oldObj, MyPojo newObj) {
   return TheMagicLibraryIAmLookingFor.createDifferenceView(oldObj, newObj);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a library? library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Only if there is no simpler way to do this out of the box with pure Java or common libraries like Spring. That's why I was asking

Comment: apache commons might have something. But it's pretty rare to want to craft an object instance with the differences instead of just getting some sort of map structure or something.

Comment: This requires reflection...using reflection you can iterate over all fields and compare

Comment: @Selbi is the solution you need applicable to ANY type of classes? Or is this only to be used with specific, custom POJOs? I am asking because inheritance and/or composition will complicate the answer and as many indicated, will require reflection which is undesirable.

Comment: @hfontanez Only one specific POJO that is never extended and doesn't have any nested types. Only Strings, ints, bools, etc.

Comment: I have update my answer to work with fields and create a new object based on the deltas

Comment: Apache Commons Lang is to rescue: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionDiffBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection.

Sample input

```
MyPojo oldObj = new MyPojo("a", "b", "c",true,5);
MyPojo newObj = new MyPojo("a", "b", "x",true,3);
```

Output: Creates a new difference object:

```
MyPojo{field1='null', field2='null', field3='x', field4=null, field5=3}
```

Rough idea as a starter using a map of field names to their values:
(This needs to be tested and add error checking)

```
public class CompareFields {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        MyPojo oldObj = new MyPojo("a", "b", "c",true,5);
        MyPojo newObj = new MyPojo("a", "b", "x",true,3);
        Map<String, Object> mapping = mapDeltas(oldObj,newObj);

        System.out.println(mapping);

        // now map to constructor / properties etc....

        MyPojo newDeltas = createNewObj(mapDeltas(oldObj, newObj));

        System.out.println(newDeltas);

    }

    private static Map<String, Object> mapDeltas(MyPojo oldObj, MyPojo newObj) throws IllegalAccessException {
        HashMap<String, Object> mapFieldNamesToValues= new HashMap<>();

        Field[] fieldsA = oldObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] fieldsB = newObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        // add type and name checking etc...
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldsA.length && i<fieldsB.length; i++) {
                Field fieldA = fieldsA[i];
                Field fieldB = fieldsB[i];
                fieldA.setAccessible(true);
                fieldB.setAccessible(true);
                if(fieldA.get(oldObj).equals(fieldB.get(newObj))){
                    mapFieldNamesToValues.put(fieldA.getName(), null);
                }else{
                    mapFieldNamesToValues.put(fieldB.getName(),fieldB.get(newObj));
                }

        }

        return mapFieldNamesToValues;
    }

    private static MyPojo createNewObj(Map<String, Object> mapDeltas) throws IllegalAccessException {

        MyPojo newObj = new MyPojo();

        Field[] fields = newObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        // add type and name checking etc...
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length ; i++) {
            Field field = fields[i];
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = mapDeltas.get(field.getName());
            if(value!=null){

                field.set(newObj, value);
            }
        }

        return newObj;
    }
}
```

And the POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private Boolean field4;
    private Integer field5;

    public MyPojo(String field1, String field2, String field3, Boolean field4, Integer field5) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
        this.field4 = field4;
        this.field5 = field5;
    }

    public MyPojo() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPojo{" +
                "field1='" + field1 + '\'' +
                ", field2='" + field2 + '\'' +
                ", field3='" + field3 + '\'' +
                ", field4=" + field4 +
                ", field5=" + field5 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Or this library may help [Apache Commons Lang API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/package-summary.html)

More generally avoiding reflection it may be that if only a few fields change then this is an indication that you need to take another look at those POJO designs and look at separating those areas that frequently change from those that don't and maybe compose objects on that basis in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Java Reflection API to compare two objects as below. You can use the 2nd option if you have Boolean or Integer fields.

```
public Object createDifferenceView(Object one, Object two) throws Exception{
    Object result = two.getClass().newInstance();
    
     Method[] methods =  one.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
     for (Method m: methods) {
     if(m.getName().startsWith("get")) {
         String methodName = m.getName();
            methodName = "s"+methodName.substring(1, methodName.length());
            if(m.invoke(one).equals(m.invoke(two))) {
                two.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class).invoke(result, (Object)null);
            }else {
                two.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class).invoke(result, m.invoke(two));
            }
         }
     }
    return result;
    
}
```

OR

```
public Object createDifferenceView1(Object one, Object two) throws Exception {
    
    Object result = two.getClass().newInstance();
    
     Field[] fields = one.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
     for (Field f : fields) {
         f.setAccessible(true);
         if(f.get(one).equals(f.get(two)))
             f.set(result, null);
         else
             f.set(result, f.get(two)); 
         }
    return result;
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little bit of explanation would be quite useful

Comment: NONE of these solutions work. Reason: They don't return a NEW object. Both solution mutate one of the original objects which is not what the OP asked for.

"Basically, I'd like to take two objects A and B of the same class (same one, no inheritance) and create a new one with just the differences"

Comment: @hfontanez if new object is required, we can define new object at the beginning and set null or value inside if else.

Comment: @venkateshkvnh a new object IS required. I quoted you the original requirement by the OP. Modify your answer so that it does what the OP asked for.